# Is there a reason we can define a type alias for a value literal?

Tags: scala

Type aliases might typically be used like this:

`type Point = (Double, Double)`

but I was playing with the scala repl and you could do this as well:

`type Two = 2`

with this alias you can define the function:

```
scala> def three(x: Two) = x + 1
def three(x: Two): Int

scala> three(1)
-- Error:
1 |three(1)
  |      ^
  |      Found:    (1 : Int)
  |      Required: Two

scala> three(2)
val res0: Int = 3
```

As you can see `Two` really does seem to represent the singleton type of `2`. It only seems to work with value literals, not variables:

```
scala> val x = 2
val x: Int = 2

scala> type Two = x
-- Error:
1 |type Two = x
  |           ^
  |           Not found: type x
```

Also it seems to work with some function values but not others:

```
scala> type AlwaysThree = () => 3
// defined alias type AlwaysThree = () => 3

scala> type AlwaysThree = () => 2 + 1
-- Error:
1 |type AlwaysThree = () => 2 + 1
  |                           ^
  |                           Not found: type +
```

I'm wondering why scala allows this. Is there a reason this little thing is here?

Comment: If you are using scala3, you can make `type AlwaysThree = () => 2 + 1` work as your expected with `import scala.compiletime.ops.int.*`

Comment: @esse *How is that a builtin?!* You know what, it's Scala 3. I really shouldn't be surprised at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete @Silvio's answer, a great use case for these types is *union types* to define a very precise set of values a method can return or accept.

For instance:

```scala
type LastDay = 28 | 29 | 30 | 31

def getLastDayOfMonth(month: String): LastDay = ???
```

Or:

```scala
type Role = "Driver" | "Passenger"

def getInTheCar(role: Role) = ???
```

Comment: Ah I see.  Although besides brevity, is there a reason this version is better than defining an enum?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can define type aliases for any types, and `2` is a perfectly valid type. Specifically, it's the type which contains only the number `2` and nothing else.

```
type AlwaysThree = () => 3
```

A function takes arguments and has a return type. This is the function type which takes no arguments and unconditionally returns the number `3`. An example function of this type might be `() => 3`.

```
type AlwaysThree = () => 2 + 1
```

This is attempting to use an infix type alias. It's more like

```
type AlwaysThree = () => Foo[1, 2]
```

where instead of the type `Foo`, we have `+`. You could very easily *define* a type called `+`

```
type +[A, B] = A
```

and then `1 + 2` would be valid as a type. Though getting the *type* `A + B` to represent the numerical value of `A` plus that of `B` may be a bit trickier. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.